# Not allowing numbers in Glade with Python

Tags: python, numbers, literals, glade

I'm a fairly new Python programmer (started 3 days ago). I'm working as a apprentice for a civil engineer and he asked me to do some simpler tasks for his program, as of the objective I should work with is to not allow numbers from inputs in certain glade objects.

The code I've been struggling with creating is as such:

```
    def testOmHeltal (self, number1):
        textviewResultat = self.builder.get_object("textviewResultat")
        text = gtk.TextBuffer()
        try:
            #print number1.get_text()
            #temp = number1.get_text() + number1.get_text()
            temp = float(number1.get_text())

        except ValueError:
            text.set_text("ERROR: Endast Nummer")
            self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").show()
            self.builder.get_object("image12").show()
            self.builder.get_object("textviewResultat").set_buffer(text)
            return 0
        self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").hide()
        self.builder.get_object("image12").hide()


    def quit(self, widget):
        sys.exit(0)
```

This code is called upon at the location of the glade object with this line:

> > self.testOmHeltal(entryGladeObject)

Now to the problem at hand, I allways get an Float error as such:

> > File "bvf.py", line 393, in utfora
> >
> > +float(entryTjockleksskyddslager.get_text<>>>>
> >
> > ValueError: invalid literal for float<>: 0.04e

0.04e is the invalid input and line 393 is a piece of my Chiefs code, since all he uses is float all the time and I shouldn't meddle with it too much I'm kind of panicking alittle..

I understand that float can only start and end with a number to not give an error, but since my "code" bit wants an error(or rather, an exception) to start the 'hboxWarning' and 'image12' of someone using a letter instead of the supposed number, I'm at a loss at what to do ><

Instead of showing my error with hboxWarning and image12, nothing happens at all...

Any hints or advice would help alot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but the error is *not on your code*, right?

All I can assume is that there's a piece of code trying to convert the value to float *before* your verification. If that's the case, you should verify the value before any processing is done on it, or move the try-except code around the faulty code, depending on the processing itself (for example, if the processing implies database manipulation, it would be safer to do all the verifications previously).

If the error is happening *before* the line where you run `self.testOmHeltal(entryGladeObject)`, the execution of the signal/method stops right away and your code is never excecuted; that's why the warning isn't showing.